# Problem with query "NOT IN" in prestashop database

Tags: database, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a web in **prestashop 1.7**.
I need to do a query that shows me the customers that ONLY belong to a group of customers.

I have tried to do it with this query, but it shows me customers that are also in other groups but share the group that I only want to show.

I have 3 groups in Presta 2,34,932 I want to show only the clients whose are in the group 2.
But show me clientes who share others groups like 34 ,932

`SELECT id_customer, id_group FROM ps_customer_group WHERE id_group NOT IN (34, 932);`

What i do wrong?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do this is to count how many times this user is added in the table.

First we select all customers that occur in `id_group` 2. Then we will see how many times this customer appears in the table `ps_customer_group`. Because you only want customers to occur in group 2 and not in other groups, we can use the count function.

**For example**

```
SELECT * FROM ps_customer_group g WHERE g.id_group = 2 
AND (SELECT COUNT(id_group) FROM ps_customer_group WHERE id_customer = g.id_customer) = 1
```

Comment: It has worked, I had not occurred to me, I can not rate you because the account is new, but thank you very much Creezzur.